# Question about converting my answer to comment

Tags: discussion

[This](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81166/how-can-i-remove-all-password-requirements-from-a-pdf?noredirect=1#comment99184_81166) is the question I talk about.

My answer was converted to comment. But my understanding is: if document creator set password and do not want this password to be removed he/she should have a reason for this. From other side OP want to remove this password which by my understanding is illegal action.

So my (ex) answer is perfectly reasonable. Can someone clarify the reason for convert this answer to comment?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question.

I'm not a legal expert, so please understand that these are just thoughts, and nothing more.

Our planet is a large place.  Our community has no way of knowing which legal jurisdictions are involved, or whether these actions would be legal or illegal in these jurisdictions.  It could even possibly be *illegal* for the OP to *not* remove the encryption in some jurisdictions (e.g. jurisdictions in which encryption is illegal).

Since the answer you provided did not recommend any software, but may be helpful, it was converted to a comment.

All quality answers are appreciated by our community, but answers without software recommendations will generally be converted to comments.

I hope this helps you understand why your answer was converted to a comment.

Comment: It seems like SE system is kind of broken. I edit my answer and add web site which say they can remove the password. But I can't undelete the answer.